# How to open PDF file in Google Chrome in new tab?

Tags: google-chrome

I know it's not question about programming but I hope I'll find an answer for my problem.

Is there a way how to force Google Chrome to open PDF files in new tab? Now Chrome opens PDF in tab which is currently opened and it's really annoying to click on "back" button to get back.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold Ctrl key when you click on PDF link.

It works the same in FireFox and IE.

Comment: Thank you it works. I thought there was some option in settings where I could adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding Ctrl when you click on the link.  Or right click on the link and open in new tab.  Or just download the file by right-click and save, then open it outside of Chrome.