# Opening a local PDF file in Chrome

Tags: pdf, google-chrome

Ok I see these 2 questions:

[How to open PDF file in Google Chrome in new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844027/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-google-chrome-in-new-tab)

[Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)

But I'm not sure they answer my question. I'm trying not to install any PDF reader (Adobe sucks) and know that Chrome will open PDFs I open from the internet. So my question, is why won't it work if the PDF is local to my machine? Is there a workaround/plugin/other browser I can use to accomplish this?

The argument of security is totally bogus; how would a PDF I'm opening on the internet be any more secure/safe than a PDF I have on my local machine?

Comment: Is this a programming related question? It looks more suited to http://superuser.com

Comment: Well, if I have to program a plugin, then yes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm running Chrome 8.0.552.18 on my computer now, under Windows 7, and I just clicked and dragged a PDF onto it, and it loaded it up no problem...

And no, it doesn't look like it's using Acrobat or Foxit, or another PDF reader... it looks like Chrome 8 does have its own PDF renderer.

Comment: Wow. Interesting indeed. Seems everyone wants to avoid Adobe software like the plague, first Apple now Google.

Comment: @SherlockSpreadsheets Yeah.. local files use the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Awesome trick! This is the URL in chrome. And FYI... the URL also worked in internet explorer. URL: `file:///C:/Users/bl0040/Dropbox/My%20folder%20Name/File%20Name.pdf`

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are on Windows. So, if your PDF is `c:\some\path\some.pdf`, simply use this URI in Chrome's address and search field:

```
 file:///C:/some/path/some.pdf
```

On Linux I'd expect this for `/some/path/some.pdf` to change to

```
 file:///some/path/some.pdf
```

(but have no chance to test this).

Comment: Your expecation for Linux is exactly correct. The first two `/` characters are part of the URI, and the third indicates the UNIX Filesystem Root `/`. That last slash, along with the rest of the line is the standard UNIX path.

Keep in mind, even on Windows instead of using `\ ` characters, it uses `/` characters, since web browsers were originally made for Steve Jobs's NeXTSTEP OS (which is a BSD UNIX system that later became Mac OSX)